# auto increments get old values after deleting records in mysql

Tags: mysql

In MySQL table `TabRespond` I have a field `RN` which is primary field and set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

My one php process 1 continue add records in this table. and another php process 2 read and DELETE the records from same table.

My php process 2 wants RN values in the table must be unique. (As I set it Auto_Increment it should be Unique). Process 1 add daily 40 to 50 records in that table and same are read and deleted by process 2.

It worked fine for some days. One day I was very SHOCKED to see that the next RN value come 345 (Where the last record read value of RN is 765) that means instead of next RN value 766, it comes 345,346,347. That values of RN already taken by process 2, which required RN must unique.

How can I solve this problem so that RN Auto-Increment should not Auto RESET to previous values.

Comment: Auto_Increment does not show older values and you cannot re-insert the values once added, although they are deleted. May be we are missing something. It will be better if you post your mysql table query or structure or some PHP code you are having.

Comment: # Name Type  Collation  Attributes Null Default Extra  
 1 RN  bigint(20)       No  None  AUTO_INCREMENT